# Removing a data in database. Detached instance

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

When i try remove data from database:

```
@Override
    public void delete(PatientCard patientCard) {
        PatientCard toRemoved = em.merge(patientCard);
        em.remove(toRemoved);
    }
```

i get a error:

> WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on
>   EJB PatientCardDao, method: public void
>   pl.ePrzychodnia.dao.daoClass.PatientCardDao.delete(pl.ePrzychodnia.model.PatientCard)
>   WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy275.delete(Unknown Source)
>           at pl.ePrzychodnia.mb.PatientCardMB.delete(PatientCardMB.java:149)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>           at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
>           at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
>           at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
>           at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
>           at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
>           at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>           at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
>           at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>           at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>           at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>           at pl.ePrzychodnia.filter.FilterLogin.doFilter(FilterLogin.java:49)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance
>   pl.ePrzychodnia.model.PatientCard#1
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3DeleteEventListener.performDetachedEntityDeletionCheck(EJB3DeleteEventListener.java:45)
>           at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:86)
>           at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:52)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:766)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:744)
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.remove(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:253)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.remove(EntityManagerWrapper.java:303)
>           at pl.ePrzychodnia.dao.daoClass.PatientCardDao.delete(PatientCardDao.java:48)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>           at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
>           at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
>           at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>           at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor457.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
>           at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
>           ... 52

But when i change to:

```
@Override
    public void delete(PatientCard patientCard) {
        PatientCard toRemoved = em.merge(em.find(PatientCard.class, patientCard.getId()));
        em.remove(toRemoved);
    }
```

data is deleted. Why?

I wanted to see if the entity is managed:

```
toRemoved = em.merge (patientCard)
    boolean a = em.contains (toRemoved);
    System.out.println (a);
```

And i see true.

So why?

```
em.remove(toRemoved);
```

in one case generates an error?

Comment: Why do you want to merge the instance before removing it?

Comment: Also, what means `in one case generates an error`? Could you please provide code examples of your method where the exception occurs and where not? Also, the big exception stack trace is rather unneccessary. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

A detached entity is an entity which is **not** managed by any entity manager, but represent objects in the database.

Since it is not managed by the entity manager, it can not be removed using it. Therefore, you must retreive it using `find()` on the entity manager before so it gets managed by the entity manager.

So, `find()` would be enough here, since you do not persist the changed properties (i.e. `merge()` is not needed).

Comment: Yes, but is not my problem. Why merge(PatientCard) not work? I check if entity is detached before merge, and i get is not detached. Why next i can't removed entity?

Comment: @Orange91 just because it is not detached does not mean it is managed by the entity manager. It could be new as well.

Comment: In documentation about contains: Check if the instance is a managed entity instance belonging to the current persistence context.